# Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 Installation notes

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, windows-server

Needs help with Microsoft Dynamics Ax 2012, installation and configuration.
Any info will be helpful, totally new to this technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Personal notes:
You need to download the Dynamics ax on a Windows server 2008 r2 or windows server 2012.
While checking requisites, if you have an error with a configure check box enabled, use this check box to let the system automatically solve the issue for you.
When installing SQL server, note to enable the following features:
-Data Base engine services
-Full text search
-Analysis services
-Reporting services
-Business Intelligence
-Management tools basic
-Management tools Complete
-SQL client connectivity SDK
-Microsoft Sync features

Installing Core System:
A core Microsoft Dynamics AX system consists of 
-an instance of an Application Object Server (AOS),
-an application file server,
-a database,
-and at least one client.
These components can be installed on computers arranged in a variety of topologies, but without all elements your system will not run.
For more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548645(v=ax.10).aspx

In order to install Dynamics ax 2012 you need to have:
Database: DB server can be on a dedicated box or on the same machine. For production purposes recommended to have a dedicated machine.

> > I installed Microsoft SQL server 2008 r2 as the database engine.
> >     Prerequisites check: 
> >     When checking the prerequisites, the SQL Full text search service is required.
> >     If not installed on your SQL server, you have to add this feature to the existing SQL instance, to do so, please follow the steps in the link below:
> >      http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/adding-sql-full-text-search-to-an-existing-sql-server/
> >     Install the Microsoft Dynamics AX databases [AX 2012]: 
> >     http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355075.aspx

Server Components
    -Application Object Server (AOS)
    -Web server components
        -Enterprise Portal (EP)
        -Enterprise Search
        -Helper Server

> > You need to have the server components; you can have one AOS or multiple AOSs, which will speed up the operation, and allows you to have more clustered environment.
> >
> > EP gives you similar functionality to the client application over the web
> >     Enterprise Search gives you the capability to find different info in your environment using a client utility or enterprise portal
> >     Help server to get the latest info from Microsoft
> >     Prerequisites check: 
> >     Download: Microsoft Search Server 2010 Express 
> >     http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18914
> >     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa497037(v=ax.10).aspx
> >     Business intelligence components
> >         -Reporting Services extensions
> >         -Analysis Services configuration
> >     Reporting Services extensions: to create reports using visual studio or report builder, modify the existing reports, package them and upload to Dynamics ax
> >     Analysis Services configuration: to use AOL app and AOL TP, Dynamics ax automatically creates OAL app cubes to analyze the business data.

Client components 
    -Client
    -Office add-ins
    -Remote desktop services integration

> > Client components very important to Dynamics ax users to be able to access Dynamics ax features.
> >     You can add to the client app the office add-ins such as excel. Fully integrated with Dynamics ax 2012
> >     you can also add remote connection to the client app.
> >     Developer tools
> >         -Debugger
> >         -Visual studio tools: Note, You need VS2010 (Only 2010 will work) with Dynamics 2012
> >         -Trace Parser

Integration components
    -Web services on IIS: Based on WCF
    -NET Business Connector: Gate way between Dynamics ax and Visual studio or any other 3ed party languages
    -Synchronization proxy for Microsoft Project Server
    -Synchronization service for Microsoft Project Server : these 2 components necessary to update info project server 2010 and dynamics as

Management utilities: uses windows power shell

Microsoft Dynamics ax 2012 
Flowchart: Installation processes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496434(v=ax.10).aspx

Hardware and software requirements
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548679(v=ax.10).aspx

Installing a core system – Very important link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa548645(v=ax.10).aspx